# Excel Web Add-in Custom Function using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2019, office-js, excel-addins, custom-functions-excel

I have created Excel Web Addin project using VS 2019 and trying to incorporate Custom Functions into this project. Unfortunately all the documentation on MSDN refer to Yeoman generator so I am not sure either VS created project doesn't support custom functions OR I am missing something?
I have added following factor under HOST

```html
<AllFormFactors>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="CustomFunctions">
            <Script>
              <SourceLocation resid="CustomFunction.Script" />
            </Script>
            <Page>
              <SourceLocation resid="CustomFunction.Page" />
            </Page>
            <Namespace resid="CustomFunction.Namespace" />
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </AllFormFactors>
```

And all the URL point to the files which I created

```html
<bt:Url id="CustomFunction.Script" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/CustomFunctions/CustomFunction.js" />
        <bt:Url id="CustomFunction.Page" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/CustomFunctions/CustomFunction.html" />
```

My CustomFunction.js file content looks like:

```js
// The initialize function must be run each time a new page is loaded.
(function () {
    Office.initialize = function (reason) {
        // If you need to initialize something you can do so here.
    };

    /**
     * Add two numbers
     * @customfunction
     * @param {number} first First number
     * @param {number} second Second number
     * @returns {number} The sum of the two numbers.
     */
    function add2(first, second) {
        return first + second;
    }

    CustomFunctions.associate("ADD2", add2);

})();
```

And HTML file look like

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/custom-functions-runtime.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I can debug the project successfully and when I run it, Excel open but no add-in loaded into it.
Can anyone point out the right direction please?

Comment: Will the add-in be loaded successfully when there's no Custom Function? Or the issue only happens when Customer Functions exist in the add-in?

Comment: Hi @Phoebe123, Yes Addin load successfully before making any change for Custom Function. Its really strange, all documentation of Custom Functions only use Yoeman generator (not VS).

Comment: Have you figured this out? I think that you can't create custom functions in VS 2019. In the manifest file I have this comment:

<!-- Form factor. Currently only DesktopFormFactor is supported. -->

So there is no place for AllFormFactors I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the JSON archive with the metadata:

```
<AllFormFactors>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="CustomFunctions">
            <Script>
              <SourceLocation resid="Functions.Script.Url" />
            </Script>
            <Page>
              <SourceLocation resid="Functions.Page.Url"/>
            </Page>
            <Metadata>
              <SourceLocation resid="Functions.Metadata.Url" />
            </Metadata>
            <Namespace resid="Functions.Namespace" />
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </AllFormFactors>
```

You have to configure your metadata JSON manually :

[Manually create JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-json)

You can create a new folder with HTML, JS, and JSON archives. Then, you point them in the manifest (page, script, and metadata).